# How to store timestamp in db with Zend_Date?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I keep trying to insert a timestamp to the db with $rowUser->fecha = new Zend_Date(); but when I check the db I always find '0000-00-00 00:00:00' in that field.

I added the 'fecha' column (the one with the timestamp) with a MySQL ALTER statement, so maybe that's the prolem...I don't know. Not sure if it's my zend or SQL which is failing. Please Mods, don't close the thread if the question seems vague, I'll change or look for more info if necessary.

Comment: Does it work okay if you put a date constant there?

Comment: @wallyk, for some reason it does seem to change the fecha values when I update other fields in the table since it's set ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ... but I don't know what I should leave there instead if I want it to do the same thing on row creation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well for whoever may care about this or may have a similar issue in the future I've found a way around this. In the user model:

```
$rowUser = $this->createRow();

    if($rowUser) {
        // update the row values
        $rowUser->email = $email;
        $rowUser->password = md5($password);
        $rowUser->url = $url;
        $rowUser->responsable = $responsable;
        $rowUser->role = $role;
        $rowUser->fecha = Zend_Date::now()->toString('yyyyMMddHHmmss');; // This is the important bit
        $rowUser->save();
        //return the new user
        return $rowUser;
    }
```

you could also use $rowUser->fecha = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'); but that might be troublesome if there's a db migration.

Comment: You have a double semicolon at the end of "rowUser->fecha = Zend_Date::now()->toString('yyyyMMddHHmmss');;"

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'll need to use something similar to

```
$rowUser->fecha = new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()');
```

I think you can use the Zend_Date component, but you'll have to convert it to the correct format as a string representation to insert.